# Discord.js | Cannot access "lol" before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot to send random images in embeds  but this logs in the terminal:

```
let lol = Math.floor (Math.random() * (lol - 1 + 1)) + 1;
                                       ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'lol' before initialization
```

This is the code its referring to:

```
case 'gif':

            let maxImageNumber1 = 213;
            let lol = Math.floor (Math.random() * (lol - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            let imageName1 = `${maxImageNumber1}.gif`
            let imagePath1 = `./GIF/${imageName1}`
            
            let file2 = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath1);
            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
                embed1.setImage(`attachment://${imageName1}`)
            message.channel.send({ files: [file2], embed: embed1 });
            break;

                case 'aes':
                    let maxImageNumber = 100;
                    let imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (maxImageNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
                    let imageName = `${imageNumber}.jpg`
                    let imagePath = `./images/${imageName}`
                    
                    let file1 = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath);
                    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
                        embed.setImage(`attachment://${imageName}`)
                    message.channel.send({ files: [file1], embed: embed });
                    break;
```

**How would i go about solving this issue?**

Comment: you cannot define `lol` variable as depending on `lol`.. also, it's never used in your script. also, -1+1 is totally useless

Comment: ` let lol = Math.floor (Math.random() * (lol - 1 + 1)) + 1;` -- 
as Greedo has already pointed out, this expression has issues. The error message you posted points to the main one: you Cannot access 'lol' before initialization. -- 'let' is the keyword you use to initialize a variable, so if you write 'let lol = ...', you won't be able to access 'lol' value until the 'let' expression is evaluated. -- Plainly, trying to define 'lol' as the result of some operation that involves the value of 'lol', makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

where you trying to obtain a random number between `1` and `maxImageNumber1`?

if so, this is the answer:

```
let maxImageNumber1 = 213;
let lol = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxImageNumber1) + 1;
let imagePath1 = `./GIF/${lol}.gif`
```